# Using ADF for REST API authentication using client certificate

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault, rest

We want to call a REST API endpoint of a SaaS application. i.e. system to system interaction.

We are using Azure Data Factory to call and we could see that ADF support(Web client activity) client certificate authentication.

We have the certificate with us. Added the certificate to AKV, configured ADF to use the certificate.

Question:

1. Do we need an app registration to be able to use?
2. What details do we need to send to the SaaS vendor so that they can recognize that our call is a legit call?
3. Are there any other steps in the process?

Comment: Were you able to achieve this? I have also similar situation.

Comment: We have a possible solutuon… we are using AzureFunctions for the authentication piece… the problem we are facing that there a ssl interception happening when are leaving the organization boundary, and the certificate is dropped. We are trying fix that, and after that hopefully it wirks. Will updated when we have a working solution

Answer (score 0):

From the way you're describing this issue, it sounds like the SaaS isn't an application that is protected using Azure AD.  In that case, the SaaS determines what credentials are suitable - likely a username and client certificate.  I can't think of a reason for you to need to create an app registration.  All of this said - you need to talk to the vendor to ask them what credentials are necessary for access.

Comment: The client does support client credentials. But that does not fit the security aspect of the company I am working for . The SaaS app is also on Azure but on a different subscription.